# Change setting within a "ClientSettingsSection" with C#

Tags: c#, system.configuration

Is it possible to change values of settings within a **ClientSettingsSection** (System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection) in a exe-configuration? Unfornately the settings in the ClientSettingsSection collection are **read-only** !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use user settings for settings you want to change at runtime. Take a look at [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)